# Strange behavior in firefox, auto select radio button with value "Nein"

Tags: html, forms, validation, firefox, radio-button

I have a simple html form with two radio buttons. One has the value "Ja" (German word for yes) the other has the value "Nein" (German word for no). None of them is checked.

When I submit the form, the radio button with the value "Nein" is selected automatically and the form will be submitted. That is not the expected behaviour. The user should select the value explicit. The problem is only treaten in firefox. Chrome and IE works as expected.

Does anyone has an idea, how to disable this behaviour? I also tried autocomplete="off" attribute, but that didn't help.

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="anmeldung.html" id="f3" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" novalidate="">
<div class="formbody">
    <input name="FORM_SUBMIT" value="auto_form_3" type="hidden">                                 
    <fieldset id="ctrl_17" class="radio_container mandatory">
          <span><input autocomplete="off" name="Teilnahme_20_09" id="opt_17_0" class="radio" value="Ja" required="" type="radio"> <label id="lbl_17_0" for="opt_17_0">Ja</label></span>
          <span><input autocomplete="off" name="Teilnahme_20_09" id="opt_17_1" class="radio" value="Nein" required="" type="radio"> <label id="lbl_17_1" for="opt_17_1">Nein</label></span>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML

Comment: please post your html code.Then only we can identify what the problem is..